# Disable GNOME (Compiz) task switcher grouping

Tags: gnome, compiz, shortcut-keys, application-switcher, ccsm

I'm currently running GNOME (*GNOME Shell 3.10.4*; Compiz) on **ubuntu**.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does the expected (and "correct") behavior of showing the task switcher, enabling to switch between current open applications.

However, it groups multiple "instances" of the same application (example, **gnome-terminal**) and requires extra key presses to be able to switch between the instances.

---

Is there a way to disable the grouping behavior? I've looked around in `ccsm` and was unable to find anything of relevance.

Any hints you share would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The normal behavior doesn't require extra key presses to be able to to switch between the instances. When you get to an application that has multiple instances just keep a while the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key pressed (maximum 2 seconds) and you will see that after you can switch between instances also using the same shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Just don't take your finger from the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Anyway, if you want more, the behavior about you asked can be obtained using [**CompizConfig Settings Manager**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/) (you said that you have it installed). After you open it, first enable **Application Switcher**:

[image: CCSM - Application Switcher]

Second, go inside to **Application Switcher**, select **General** tab and play a little with those options until you get what you wish. Personally, I made the following selections:

[image: CCSM - Application Switcher - General tab]

And the result is:

[image: Application Switcher]

Comment: This does not work, both the Gnome switcher and Compiz task switcher overlap.

Comment: How to increase number of applications shown at a time. I've a widescreen monitor and it only shows 3-4 icons at a time leaving empty space to left/right of switcher.

Comment: You can show all applications by pressing the "Super" key.

Comment: Does not work .

Comment: @JanM. *"This does not work, both the Gnome switcher and Compiz task switcher overlap"* If you get overlapping application switchers, you have to disable the other one. For example, in CCSM, go to "Desktop > Ubuntu Unity Plugin > Switcher" and disable the `<Alt>Tab` keybinding.

Answer (score 29):

I hate the *grouping windows* function. Anti-programmer. I don't want to remember which window should I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and which window should I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>.

Just one combo-key:  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for all the windows, all the time!!

So here is the solution for Ubuntu GNOME:

1. Open `dconf-editor`.
2. Go to `org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings`.
3. Move the value 'Tab' from `switch-applications` to `switch-windows`.

Done.

*Refer to: [Mad Physicist's answer to the same question on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/860001/227795)*

Comment: In my case it meant moving '<Alt>Tab' but this was definitely a simple solution. Worked well on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Should be the excepted answer, as it does not need any additional tool. Thx!

Comment: This is THE answer.

Comment: mind that after removing all these unecessary compiz components you'll have to touch and save again the settings in the dconf editor.

Comment: The keyword "change applications" -> "change windows" is the key! Changed this in my keyboard shortcuts, et voila!

Comment: worked on Manjaro. (force task selector to not group)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I disabled "Application Switcher" and enabled "Shift Switcher" and retained the default options. The windows are not grouped anymore and you get a 'fancy' switcher.

In the screenshot below, the multiple Firefox windows are not grouped together.

[image]

---

For this to work, you will have to install compiz-config settings manager and its plugins. Run this command on the terminal.

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins compiz-plugins-extra
```

Once they are installed, launch compiz config settings manager and go the section 'Window Management'. Thst's where you find both the "Application Switcher" and "Shift Switcher" options.

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: at least explain you answer that what is "Application Switcher" and "Shift Switcher", what are the steps to achieve this, how to disabled "Application Switcher" and enabled "Shift Switcher".

Comment: @RayVaniya I have included more instructions on how to disabled "Application Switcher" and enabled "Shift Switcher".