# How to take screenshot of shutter's menu?

Tags: screenshot, shutter

With the application famously known as `shutter`, one can take screenshot of about every GUI element: like windows, hidden windows, menus, cursor tip etc.

The only thing shutter can't take screenshot of is *itself*.

Using the default `screenshot` app, we can take screenshot of `shutter`.But I need to take screenshot of a shutter's menu, which is not possible(as it seems to me) by either using `shutter` or `screenshot`.

So is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the default screenshot tool, (`gnome-screenshot` in Gnome, no idea in Unity)  and give it a delay of say, 5 seconds. Then navigate to your desired menu and wait, the screenshot will show the chosen menu.

[image]

That then allows you to take pictures like:

[image]

It's the same idea as a regular camera. To take a picture of your camera, you need to use another camera.

Comment: BTW you can also take picture of camera by pointing it towards mirror.

Comment: @AdityaPatil Not ideal for readability of instructional screenshots... But you could also use the (lubuntu-default) commandline screenshot utility `scrot` with a sleepcommand: `sleep 5 && scrot`

Comment: @terdon Excuse me, I ment to aim at the OP, my mistake

Comment: Delay will also enable you to take screenshots like [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/433134/163331)